# Wordpress Detect Click on Gallery Shortcode Preview in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

Working on customizing the wordpress gallery with some different settings for different gallery types.

Short of the long is I'm using multiple wp_editors on page and I'm having a focus problem when jumping between editors.

I'm making use of `wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend` to switch between gallery types and display different js templates.

The functionality is actually all good and gallery shortcodes are going where they need to and being updated as needed.

For certain gallery types I am extending the attachment details with
an extend that looks something like this slimed down version:

```
var $gal_media = wp.media;
$gal_media.view.Attachment.Details = $gal_media.view.Attachment.Details.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function(){
    var check_active_editor =  window.wpActiveEditor;
    return this;
  }
});
```

The problem lies here when I'm attempting to detect the current editor during the render part of the function with `window.wpActiveEditor;`

It's working correctly providing you get focus on the current editor but if you just click the gallery preview or edit gallery pencil `window.wpActiveEditor;` will return the last focused editor.

Tried several different attempts to change focus on the editor in the wp_editor call using on click events during init like so:

```
'tinymce' => array(
  'init_instance_callback' => 'function(gallery_editor) {
    gallery_editor.on("click", function(){
      tinyMCE.get(gallery_editor.id).focus();
    });
  }'
)
```

but they are not called when clicking on the gallery preview or edit.

Any suggestion on either:

1) Getting the proper id?
Obviously the Gallery knows it as it's returning the shortcode to the proper editor.

or

2) Toggling Focus/Blur on Multiple Editors when Gallery Preview or Edit button is pressed.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds themselves in a similar situation I was able to resolve this issue with an on click callback on my editors that cycles through all the editors and removes the `data-mce-selected` attribute from any other gallery nodes that were selected. 
Then it sets focus on the editor that was just clicked.
Not the prettiest but it's behaving as expected.

The key for me was using `tinyMCE.dom.DomQuery`

```
'tinymce' => array(
  'init_instance_callback' => 'function(ed) {
    ed.on("click", function(){
      for (edId in tinyMCE.editors){
        if(edId !== ed.id){
          var this_editor = tinyMCE.get(edId);
          var $ = tinyMCE.dom.DomQuery;
          $("div[data-wpview-type]", this_editor.dom.doc).removeAttr("data-mce-selected");
        }
      }
      tinyMCE.get(ed.id).focus();
    });
  }'
)
```